# visual studio 2012 publish mvc 4 site to godaddy

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, web-deployment, webdeploy

From visual studio 2012 i am trying to publish my mvc 4 site to godaddy (windows plesk panel) but cannot get the Connection right.

how do i get this information:
Service Url?
Username - is this my go daddy username and pass?
Destination URL?

i have tried a combination of "www.godaddy.com" and my domain that i purchased, but have not been successful.

i get the following error:
Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("[domain]"). On the remote computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the required process ("Web Management Service") is started.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE.)

i then tried the IP that Go daddy said my site was on and i got UserNotAdmin:
Error   1   Web deployment task failed. (Connected to '[ip]' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on '[ip]'.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.)

any information on how to upload the site step by step would be cool (im a big noob at this :))

Comment: Did you follow these steps?  http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/6639/using-mvc3-applications-on-your-hosting  I remember deploying to GoDaddy recently and that the articles provided by GoDaddy were all I needed.